# Error with apache virtual host configuration for symfony project

Tags: apache2, symfony

I created the project using Symfony framework, and when I am runing build in server in prod or dev env runs ok, But now I move project to debian server, install apache and create virtual host. It shows only directory list and not starts the app. I think that is something wrong with my virual host configuration. I am using Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server, PHP 5.6.19-0+deb8u1 (cli).

Here is the code for virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mose
ServerAlias 10.5.0.62

DocumentRoot /var/www/mose/web
<Directory /var/www/mose/web/>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    Allow from All

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options -MultiViews
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>

</Directory>

# uncomment the following lines if you install assets as symlinks
# or run into problems when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets
# <Directory /var/www/mose>
#     Options FollowSymlinks
# </Directory>

# optionally disable the RewriteEngine for the asset directories
# which will allow apache to simply reply with a 404 when files are
# not found instead of passing the request into the full symfony stack
<Directory /var/www/mose/web/bundles>
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine Off
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: if I done that it redirect me to /app.php and it is empty page

Comment: correct, now you should check yours logs.

Comment: Tnx I found the problem. One of directoys did not have write permissions. But there is one more question. Now the links are like domain/app.php/login , how can I done the links without show app.php in url. Like domain/login just like in dev env? I try to use RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}] but it is the same resoult?

Comment: I found the problem. It only needs to add module to apache. "sudo a2enmod rewrite". Tnx for help.

Answer (score 0):

The right answer was AllowOverride All from  Dawid Sajdak. Tnx for help